# Shortcut to select next bone in chain

Tags: rigging, shortcut

I can select all bones in a bone chain in sequence by using "ctrl+" shortcut. However if I just want to move to the next bone (in the chain), highlighting it and unselecting the previous one. Is there a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the next or previous bone in the same chain, do this:

- Select the armature <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Go to Edit Mode <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- Go to `level up` <kbd>[</kbd> or `level down` <kbd>]</kbd>

[image: Animated GIF keys to navigate in bone armature]